# starbase gives 405 when trying to connect to hbase

Tags: python, hbase

I'm trying to read and write to hbase through the REST API, I have it running on the machine at port 8085 (can see it at XXXXX:8085/rest.jsp)

I've made this script to test and it gives me 405 (I think it's "method not allowed" but I'm not sure):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from starbase import Connection
from socket import gethostname

hostname = gethostname()

print "hostname: %r" % hostname

con = Connection(host=hostname, port=8085)

print con.tables()
```

I think I have a problem with prerequisites but I'm also not sure, perhaps someone with more experience can help.

Are there nicer solutions to connect hbase and python?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`starbase` works with `StarGate` http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/Hbase/Stargate. `Stargate` runs on port 8000 by default. If you have the `StarGate` running, you should be able to see the list of tables by just accessing the XXXXX:8000 (8085 in your case). If you don't see that, you're probably running the very old and deprecated version of the REST API.

You could try `Apache Thrift` framework http://thrift.apache.org  or `happybase` (which is based on the `Apache Thrift` framework) https://github.com/wbolster/happybase.

`Apache Thrift` is much faster than the REST API.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm not sure why it doesn't work and we moved to Thrift. I'm not sure if to accept your answer or not (I don't know if this really solves, but moving to thrift is a good tip!).